# Rewrite htaccess erase a string

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to remove a string from a URL:

```
http://www.example.com/wp/post-id/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+my-feed-example+%28feedexample.com+escape+this+string+now%29&utm_content=FeedBurner
```

To:

```
http://www.example.com/test/post-number/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+my-feed-example+&utm_content=FeedBurner
```

I want to erase this string:

```
%28feedexample.com+escape+this+string+now%29
```

`post-id` is more than 1000 (posts), so I can't redirect (301) all my links manually.

Is it possible? and how ?

Comment: http://php.net/parse_url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(wp/post-id/\?.*?utm_campaign=.*?)\%28feedexample\.com\+escape\+this\+string\+now\%29([^\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: I tested it on my Apache and it worked fine and remove that part from URL. Do you have any other rule in this .htaccess?

Comment: It gave me this URL back: `/wp/post-id/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+my-feed-example+&utm_content=FeedBurner`